# How to pass form values as FormData in reactjs on submit function

Tags: forms, reactjs, dynamic, axios

I have a dynamic form generated using json data and I need to pass the form input values on submit. I'm planning to send the values as formdata. I have created submit function but i don't know how to append the values in formdata and need to pass through post method using Axios. I'm new to react can anyone tell me how to do this. Below is my code.

```
var DATA = {
  "indexList": [{
    "Label": "Name",
    "Type": "text",
    "Regex": "",
    "Default_Val": "",
    "Values": {
      "Key": "",
      "Value": ""
    },
    "Validtion Msg": "",
    "Script": "",
    "Mandatory": "Y",
    "maxLength":"16",
    "minLength":"7",
    "format":"Alphanumeric",
    "cssClassName": "form-control",
    "Placeholder": ""
  },
  {
    "Label": "Select Language",
    "Type": "dropdown",
    "Regex": "",
    "Default_Val": "English",
    "Values": [{
      "Key": "option1",
      "Value": "English"
    },{
      "Key": "option2",
      "Value": "Spanish"
    }],
    "Validtion Msg": "",
    "Script": "",
    "Mandatory": "Y",
    "maxLength":"",
    "minLength":"",
    "format":"",
    "cssClassName": "form-control",
    "Placeholder": ""
  },
  {
    "Label": "Type",
    "Type": "radio",
    "Regex": "",
    "Default_Val": "",
    "Values": [{
      "Key": "option1",
      "Value": "Form1"
    }, {
      "Key": "option2",
      "Value": "Form2"
    }, {
      "Key": "option3",
      "Value": "Form3"
    },{
      "Key": "option4",
      "Value": "Form4"
    },{
      "Key": "option5",
      "Value": "Form5"
    }],
    "Validtion Msg": "",
    "Script": "",
    "Mandatory": "Y",
    "maxLength":"",
    "minLength":"",
    "format":"",
    "cssClassName": "form-control",
    "Placeholder": ""
  }
  ]
};

var Menu = React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {
    return {
    }
  },

  _renderElement: function(group){
    switch(group.Type){
      case 'text':
        return (
          <input
            className={group.cssClassName}
            id={group.Label}
            placeholder={group.Placeholder}
            required={group.Mandatory == 'Y' ? true : false}
          />
        );

      case 'dropdown':
        return (
          <select className={group.cssClassName}>
            <option value="">{group.Placeholder}</option>
            {group.Values.map(el => <option>{el.Value}</option>)}
          </select>
        );

      case 'radio':
        return (
          <div className={group.Type}>
            <div for="let value of group.Values">
              {group.Values.map(el=> (
                <label><input name="radios"/>{el.Value}</label>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
  },

  renderForm: function () {
    var data = DATA.indexList;
    return data.map(group => {
      return (
        <div>
          <label for={group.Label}>{group.Label}</label>
          <div>
            {this._renderElement(group)}
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    });
  },


  _onSubmit: function () {
    let formData = new FormData();
    var data1 = DATA.indexList;
    data1.map(group => {
      formData.append(group.Label); // How to get the input value here as a second parameter, so than i can pass the label name and corresponding value to form data.
    });

    const config = {
      headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
    }

    Axios.post('',formData, config)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
      });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (    
      <div className="container">
        <br/>
        <div className="panel panel-primary">
          <div className="panel-heading">Form</div>
          <div className="panel-body">
            <form>
              <div className="form-group">
                <div className="col-xs-5">
                  {this.renderForm()}
                  <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onSubmit={this._onSubmit()}>Submit</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>      
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Menu/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To post the `FormData` using `axios`, you need specify in `header` that you are sending `FormData`, for that `content-type` should be `multipart/form-data`.

Check this, how to use `FormData` with `axios`:

```
let formData = new FormData();    //formdata object

formData.append('name', 'ABC');   //append the values with key, value pair
formData.append('age', 20);

const config = {     
    headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
}

axios.post(url, formData, config)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have edited the question with your updated code. I want to pass the input values as second parameter to formdata so that i can see the label and corresponding value in formdata. I tred but Im not able to resolve it.

Answer (score 26):

You can access FormData like this:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    // Prevent default behavior
    event.preventDefault();

    const data = new FormData(event.target);
    // Access FormData fields with `data.get(fieldName)`
    // For example, converting to upper case
    data.set('username', data.get('username').toUpperCase());

    // Do your Axios stuff here
}
```

This is the code for the form:

```
render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="username">Enter username</label>
        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" />
        <button>Send data!</button>
      </form>
    );
```

Comment: can you explain why do you passed this in onSubmit.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your changes to your state dynamically. See the example [Here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
```

bind all your fields to your state. Exampkle

```
this.sate = { name: '', username: '', select: '' }
```

and then

```
_renderElement: function(group){
    switch(group.Type){
      case 'text':
      return <input className={group.cssClassName} 
      id={group.Label} 
      placeholder={group.Placeholder}
      value={this.state[group.name]}
      onChange={this.handleUsernameChange}
      required={group.Mandatory == 'Y'? true:   false}/>

      case 'dropdown':
      return <select className={group.cssClassName}>
      onChange={this.handleDropDropDownChange}
      <option value="">{group.Placeholder} </option>
      {group.Values.map(el => <option>{el.Value}</option>)}
      </select>



      </div>
    }
  }
```

note group.name can be username, name or what ever you name your control.

```
handleUsernameChange(event) {
    this.setState({username: event.target.value});
  }

handleDropDownChange(event) {
    this.setState({select: event.target.value});
  }
```

and then when posting

```
axios.post(url, this.state, config)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Don't forget to update your render to

```
render: function() {
    return (    
      <div className="container">
      <br/>
      <div className="panel panel-primary">
      <div className="panel-heading">Form</div>
      <div className="panel-body">
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      <div className="form-group">
      <div className="col-xs-5">


      {this.renderForm()}


             <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </div>
      </div>
      </form>
      </div>      
      </div>
      </div>
      )}
  });
```

Have a look at the doc here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

Using fetch

```js
function uploadFile(file) {
  fetch('https://path/to/api', {
    // content-type header should not be specified!
    method: 'POST',
    body: file,
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(success => {
      // Do something with the successful response
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error)
  );
}
```

Comment: it gives syntax error at response.json(). It get fixed after surrounding the statement response.json() with curly braces i.e. {response.json()}