# I'm trying to console.log the data of my imported excel file, but I can't get anything

Tags: reactjs, node.js, excel

I'm trying to import excel file to `mysql` using `nodejs`, I'm using `multer` for file handling. When I submit the form, I was able to save the excel file in my folder, but I can't console.log the data.

app.jsx

```
const App = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState();

  const upload = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    try {
    const res =  await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/api/uploadLibrary", formData);
    console.log(res)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="file" onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])} />
      <button type="button" onClick={upload}>
        Upload
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import uploadUserLibrary from './routes/uploadUserLibrary.js'
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())


app.use('/api/uploadLibrary', uploadUserLibrary )

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log(`conntected to backend on port http://localhost:${4000}`)
})
```

uploadLibrary.js

```
const router = express.Router();

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    return cb(null, "./public/files");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    return cb(null, `${Date.now()}_${file.originalname}`);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });

router.post("/", upload.single("file"), async (req, res) => {
  let fileInfo = req.file
  try {
    const workbook = XLSX.readFile(fileInfo);
    const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
    const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
    console.log(data)
  } catch (error) {}
});

export default router;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing the headers in axios config

{ headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' } }

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43085762/how-to-pass-form-values-as-formdata-in-reactjs-on-submit-function)